# Trying include '*.as' instead of <fx:script>

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml, flash-builder

I have an accordion component nested inside of a tab navigator. Each accordion pane has a form inside of it. The forms have two grids that transfer data back and forth between eachother and a few buttons to help them. I have the actionscript that controls the form.
*Thanks to The_asMan for helping me figure this part out.

In the package "forms", FormFunctions.as:

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

[Bindable]
public var originalData:ArrayCollection;

[Bindable]
public var changingData:ArrayCollection;

public function init( ):void
{
    this.changingData = new ArrayCollection( );
    this.originalData = new ArrayCollection( );
    for( var i:int = 0;i<100;i++)
    {
        var obj:Object = new Object( );
        obj.label = 'slot '+ i;
        obj.value = 's'+i;
        originalData.addItem( obj );
    }
}

public function addItem():void
{
    this.changingData.addItem(myStaticDataGrid.selectedItem );
    this.originalData.removeItemAt(myStaticDataGrid.selectedIndex);
}

public function clearList():void
{
    this.changingData.removeAll();
    init();
}
public function removeItem():void
{
    this.changingData.removeItemAt(bdgFormData.selectedIndex);
    this.originalData.addItem(bdgFormData.selectedItem );
}
```

My tab nav/accordian looks like this:

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="myTabNav">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="myFirstTab">
        <mx:Accordion id="myFirstAccordNav">
            <s:NavigatorContent id="myFirstAccordPane">
                <forms:DualGridStyle id="myFirstForm"/>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="mySecondAccordPane">
                <forms:DualGridStyle id="mySecondForm"/>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
         </mx:Accordion>
      </s:NavigatorContent>
      <s:NavigatorContent id="mySecondTab">
         <mx:Accordion id="mySecondAccordNav">
            <s:NavigatorContent id="myThirdAccordPane">
                <forms:DualGridStyle id="myThirdForm"/>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="myFourthAccordPane">
                <forms:DualGridStyle id="myFouthForm"/>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
         </mx:Accordion>
      </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

The  tag is my custom form component. Here is the code:

```
<s:Form xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="800" height="400">
<s:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout/>
</s:layout>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label id="lblFilter" x="40" y="24" text="Filter:"/>
<s:TextInput id="txtFilter" x="83" y="20" width="145"/>

<s:DataGrid id="myStaticDataGrid" left="40" top="60" width="188" 
            creationComplete="init()" dataProvider="{originalData}"/>
<s:DataGrid id="bdgFormData" top="60" width="284" dataProvider="{changingData}"
            horizontalCenter="110"/>
<s:Button id="btnAdd" label="Add" top="90" left="262" 
          click="addItem()"/>
<s:Button id="btnRemove" label="Remove" top="90" horizontalCenter="310" 
          click="removeItem()" />
<s:Button id="btnClear" label="Clear" top="120" horizontalCenter="310" 
          click="clearList()"/>

</s:Form>
```

My question is probably a simple answer. How do I get the custom form to recognize the AS functions from FormFunctions.as?

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive name.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but I think you want to make it a document class. http://www.albertx.mx/blog/flash-builder-projects/

Comment: I am just trying to simplify the code so that I don't have to have that .as file in a <fx:script> tag. The only way I can get it to work is by putting it under the <fx:script> tag. When I try to include the .as I get unknown property errors. Thanks for that link though. Its going to help with something else I need to do.

Comment: Separate the form into another mxml file and use it as a view and put the code in script tags there. Should be a lot cleaner. That's how I break up the code. Plus a lot easier to track down code you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your click event as:

```
click="addItem(event)"
```

and the addItem function as:

```
private function addItem(e:MouseEvent):void
{
```